# Adding two UMats with Modulo in EmguCV 3.2

Tags: c#, opencl, modulo, emgucv

So far I've worked with EmguCV 2.4 and calculated everything on the CPU. 
Now I'm trying to port everything to EmguCV 3.2, working with OpenCL using the UMat class.

And I'm not quite sure how to implement adding two UMats with modulo. 
In EmguCV 2.4 I did it by looping through the Matrizes

```
for (int row = 0; row < SrcMatrix1.Rows; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < SrcMatrix1.Cols; col++)
    {
        SrcMatrix1[row, col] = (SrcMatrix1[row, col] + SrcMatrix2[row, col]) % MaxValue;
    }
}
```

How would I do that in EmguCV 3.2?
Adressing each element in a UMat works differently and I haven't quite figured out yet how it works. I'd prefer to keep the calculation on the GPU, if possible without converting it to byte[] or Matrix<> because these operations are done on the CPU. 
Some example code would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have been able to determine, there is no way to accomplish this without converting to a Mat.

You might try interworking with managedCUDA, the C# wrapper around CUDA.

You could also do this in two steps, using CudaInvoke.Add() to add the matrices then do a threshold.

Doug